# How to get value of itemArr from listener?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to manipulate with variables/values located in listener? This code is introduction to my To Do list. Problem is, that everytime, I try to click on new list item, itemArr is empty. I need to return itemArr somehow.

```
const input = document.querySelector('input'),
const list = document.querySelector('.list'); //ul

let itemArr = [];

input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 13) { 
        let item = document.createElement('li');

        item.textContent = getValue();
        item.classList.add('to-do-item');
        list.appendChild(item);

        input.value = '';

        itemArr.push(item);
    }
}, false);

itemArr.forEach(function (liItem) {
    liItem.addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log('test');
    });
});


function getValue() {
    return input.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + input.value.substring(1);
}
```

Comment: Hitting ENTER on an input placed in a form submits the form. You've to add `e.preventDefault();` in case ENTER was pressed.

Comment: Your foreach on `itemArr` doesn't return anything because it's empty and that part runs only once.

Comment: Add the listener in the `keyup` handler or use event delegation and add a `click` handler on the `<ul>`/`<ol>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You iterate over `itemArr` before the user has typed something in the textbox, so it's empty *at that time*.

Items added later won't be iterated over.

You have two ways to solve this:

1. Add listeners when you add a list item:

   ```
   input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {

       if (e.keyCode == 13) { 
           let item = document.createElement('li');

           item.textContent = getValue();
           item.classList.add('to-do-item');
           list.appendChild(item);

           input.value = '';

           item.addEventListener('click', function() {
               console.log('test');
           });

           itemArr.push(item);
       }
   }, false);
   ```
2. Add a single listener to the parent, and perform actions based on `event.target`:

   ```
   list.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
       if(e.target === e.currentTarget) return //The <ul> was clicked, ignore it
       console.log('test')
       console.log('The clicked element is:', e.target)
   })
   ```